# Modify SQL_Variant Column to VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table where one of the columns has a `sql_variant` datatype. I'm trying to modify the column to `VarChar(800)` but I'm getting an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

I tried using the `Convert` statement in the `Alter` statement but I'm getting an incorrect syntax error. I would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on how this problem can be resolved. Thank you!

Script:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tmpEmployee
ALTER COLUMN bigVal Varchar(800)
```

`bigVal` is the column of `sql_variant` datatype.

This is the error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code -- and sample data -- that generates the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gordon. I have edited the question to add the code I ran.

Comment: Have you tried selecting from the table and using `try_convert` on the column?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not an easy task , if the order of column doesn't matter, just add a new column as varchar(800) and try to insert data from sql_varient to that column ,
but you have to be careful for different type of data in that column to use right casting format for example for dates and binary values

Comment: Thank you, eshirvana! I tried this but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @sqldeveloper then I don't think It would be easy to do ,

Comment: I guess I can convert everything to varchar when copying to the new column. But thank you so much for your response. I appreciate it!

Comment: @sqldeveloper please edit your question to show what you did to try this method. And what error you got.

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
UPDATE dbo.tmpEmployee
          SET bigVal = CONVERT(varchar(800),bigVal) 
          FROM tmpEmployee

ALTER TABLE dbo.tmpEmployee
ALTER COLUMN bigVal Varchar(800)
```

Comment: Hey Meysam, thanks for the reply. I tried this method already but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Please enter the tmpEmployee table data. Otherwise your problem will not be solved.